# Stored Procedure (INSERT INTO w/ Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, sql-insert

Hi have my tbl_student containing

> StudentID(Varchar), Lastname(Varchar), Firstname(Varchar),
>   Middlename(Varchar), Gender(Varchar), DateOfBirth(Date),
>   Address(Longtext), PhoneNumber(Varchar), Email(Varchar),
>   Modified(Timestamp)

I'm trying to create a Stored Procedure which is INSERT INTO the table. I can create the procedure WITHOUT the timestamp. Can somebody help me how to QUERY a Stored Procedure with timestamp in it. Thanks
i tried this Code but it doesn't work

```
INSERT INTO tbl_student VALUES (studid, ln, fn, mn, gendr, bday, addrs, cntct, eemail, modi)`
```

Can anyone help me? thanks

Comment: Start by deciding whether it is MySQL or SQL Server (2 very different things).  Then show the stored procedure and tell us what happens - `it doesn't work` is not very heloful

Comment: SQL Server timestamp is not intended to be modified by the user, the server changes the value when a record is updated. Also, timestamp is not a date/time. So, even if your sp did work it wouldn't be valid.

Comment: sorry, im using MySQL sir.. the code above is the SP i created via routines with. all the attributes are input including the timestamp(current time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's Mysql and the column type is Timestamp, we can use MySql's `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` in the insert query to set the field value, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_STUDENTS (studid, modified_time..) values (1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

Comment: You are welcome :) If my answer helped you then I would appreciate if you can accept my answer as correct one.